# Today Date + Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a link depend on current date.

Here is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var currentTime = new Date()
   var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
   var day = currentTime.getDate()
   document.write(month + "" + day + "")
</script>
```

Above Javascript will show, example: 1124 (month/day)

I want to make this link follow the current day:

```
http://example.com/JS-RESULT
```

Today date is 24 11 2014 so the url will be like this

```
<a href="http://example.com/1124">Today Budget</a>
```

How can I make this work?

p.s: i love jquery.

Comment: give `//example.com/today` link to your manager and make server-handler for this) What your question exactly? how to add four digit to string?

Comment: @vp_arth yes 4digit will go after slash like example.com/TodayDate4Digit

Comment: Really? `var url = "http://example.com"; url += "/1234";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JQuery Solution**:

```
$(function(){
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
    var day = currentTime.getDate();

    $("#content").append("<a href='http://example.com/" + month + day + "'>Today Budget</a>");
});
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ehLku1oq/

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about your question, hopefully you are looking for one of the things below:

#### How to form the URL to example.com/1124?

Perform a simple string + string in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var date = month + "" + day + "";
var url = "http://example.com/" + date;
// Do what you want with the url 
//-->
</script>
```

#### How "my manager just click the link and get into the current day" works?

Given that you have "one year list of links which have daily budgets", put all those webpages in the same folder as your current page which has `<a href="http://example.com/1124">Today Budget</a>`; or create a new folder called budgets for those daily budgets and change the url to `http://example.com/budgets/1124`.

My answer is very basic and I'm not sure if I got you correctly, let me know.

Comment: I think, he wants to get the code to generate hyperlink on the page also :)